# SuperMicro X9 and X10

Tags: motherboard, cmos, supermicro

I'm trying to understand fully that only when the CMOS battery is removed and the JBT1 Pads are shorted, the CMOS memory is clear. Is that correct?
Also, shorting the jumper pads while having the CMOS battery installed only discharges the capacitors. Is that also correct.